# Change the background color of an image which is showed by ngFor bucle

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor, ng-class

I've done a request to Itunes Api to show the results of the database. The request is with and input, where I can write a word and the Api returns me all the music/tracks/artists/albums which match with that word.

With all of this I've to show the information (which has sent inside and ARRAY) in a component, so I've get show them using ngFor (in this case with cdkVirtualFor, because all information must will be inside a scroll bar) . The problem is that in mi html there are only an article with a single title, a single trackname, a single albumname, and a SINGLE IMAGE for mark as a favourite. So, when the bucle is activated Angular travels into array and show all the data which I request, and generate a X number of articles, with diferent trackname, titlename. But at the end, Angular takes the image which marks as favourite and make a copy of a copy of a copy of it, repeating it.

So, when I try to select only a image clicking on it, all the images of the other articles are selected. I need to select and change the color of the only image that I click, not the other ones. But i don't know how I can do...

component.html

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="100px" class="container">
  <div id="carusel" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="32px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
      <mat-card *cdkVirtualFor="let result of dataUltima; let i = index" fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" id="{{result.trackId}}">
          <img mat-card-image id="artwork" src="{{result.artworkUrl100}}"/>
            <div>
              <span><h2>{{result.trackName}}</h2></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span><h3>{{result.collectionName}}</h3></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img id="{{result.trackId}}" class="heart" src="../../../assets/img/heart-inline.png" [ngClass]="{'active': state, 'inactive': !state}" (click)="changeState()">
            </div>
      </mat-card>
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import {DataShareService} from '../../services/dataShare/data-share.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'catalog',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.sass'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CatalogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public dataUltima: any[]=[]; // inside here there are the data array from Itunes
  public state: boolean;
  public text: string;
  public heartId: any;

  constructor(private _dataShareService: DataShareService) {
    this.state = false;
    this.text = "inactive";

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  changeState(){ // this is the function which changes the state
    this.text = (this.state) ?  "inactive" : "active";
    this.state = !this.state;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve it, but one thing I can think of right now is to use an array to keep track of the selected images.

component.html

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="100px" class="container">
  <div id="carusel" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="32px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
      <mat-card *cdkVirtualFor="let result of dataUltima; let i = index" fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" id="{{result.trackId}}">
          <img mat-card-image id="artwork" src="{{result.artworkUrl100}}"/>
            <div>
              <span><h2>{{result.trackName}}</h2></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span><h3>{{result.collectionName}}</h3></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img id="{{result.trackId}}" class="heart" src="../../../assets/img/heart-inline.png" [ngClass]="{'active': selected.indexOf(result.trackId) != -1, 'inactive': selected.indexOf(result.trackId) == -1}" (click)="changeState(result.trackId)">
            </div>
      </mat-card>
  </div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import {DataShareService} from '../../services/dataShare/data-share.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'catalog',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.sass'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CatalogComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() public dataUltima: any[]=[]; // inside here there are the data array from Itunes
  public selected: number[];
  public text: string;
  public heartId: any;

  constructor(private _dataShareService: DataShareService) {
    this.state = false;
    this.text = "inactive";

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  changeState(id:number){ // this is the function which changes the state
    if(selected.indexOf(id) == -1) {
        selected.push(id);
    } else {
        selected.splice(selected.indexOf(id), 1);
    }
  }
}
```

So every time that an image is clicked, it will add that id to an array if it isn't selected and it will take it out if it is. The selected class is determined by whether or not the id is in that array, so you should be able to select multiple images. Hope this helps.